# OSError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found

Tags: import, oserror, libm

I installed opensmile package using pip. Installation does not give any issue.
But when I import opensmile, it gives
`` OSError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /personal/su/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opensmile/core/bin/linux/libSMILEapi.so) ``
May I know how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. List the current versions installed `nvm ls`
2. If version 16 is no installed `nvm install 16`
3. Change version 16 `nvm use v16.x.x`
4. Verify version `nvm version`